# C String Passing

Tags: c, string, pass-by-reference

If I am reading a C string such as:
    char myData[100];
and I want to process this data and produce a copy out of it, so my code looks like:

```
char myData[100], processedData[50];

loop
    fill myData from file...
    setProcessedData(myData, processedData);
    store processedData to file...
```

where setProcessedData is a function that returns a processed string. let's say for simplicity it returns a substring

```
void setProcessedData (char *myData, char *processedData) {
     memCopy( processedData, myData, 5);
}
```

Is what I am doing something wrong? Like creating extra objects/strings? is there a better way to do it?

Let's say I read string from file which contains *
    I am* A T*est String* But Ho*w to Process*.
I want to get substring which has the first 3 *s. So my processedData
    I am* A t*est String*

and I want to do this for all lines of a file as efficient as possible.

Thanks

Comment: without seeing the actual code we can't tell you're doing something wrong, if you are getting errors you should post them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that your function is inherently unsafe, this because you make assumption about the allocated memory by parameters you pass to the function.

If someone is going to call `setProcessedData` by passing a string **which is shorter than 5 bytes then bad things will happen**.

In addition you are copying memory with `memcpy` by using a raw dimension, a safer approach, even if it is quite picky in this situation, is to use `sizeof(char)*5`.

Best thing you can do, though, is to follow the same approach used by safer functions of standard library like `strcpy` vs `strncpy`: you pass a third parameter which is the maximum length that should be copied, eg:

```
void processData(const char *data, char *processedData, unsigned int length) {
  memcpy(processedData,data,length*sizeof(char));
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't know the maximum length until I process the string.  Let's say the string has *'s. So I read it from file:
    I am* A t*est String* But How* To Find* Out.

And I want to extract substring as the first 3 *s. So processedData will be
    I am* A t*est String*
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can improve your code:

1. Making the input string pointer `const` (i.e. `const char* myData`), to mark that `myData` is an **input string** and its content is not modified by the function.
2. Pass the **size of the destination buffer**, so in your function you can do proper checks and avoid buffer overruns (a security enemy).